# pypl store function to update a record is not working

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, plpython

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.7 and Python 2.7.6. I am writing a plpython function to update a row in user table and my code is as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_user(myid int, mymail text, myname text) RETURNS text AS $$
    from plpy import spiexceptions
    plan=plpy.prepare("UPDATE auth_user SET email=$2, username=$3 WHERE id = $1",
    ["int"] ["text"]["text"])
    rv=plpy.execute(plan, [myid,myemail,myusername])
    return rv
    $$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

I am able to create this function successfully in postgres DB but while I am trying to execute it via below command on postgres shell:

```
select update_user(1,"xyz@xyz.com@sifymail.com","updatedname");
```

I am getting following error:

```
ERROR:  column "amarshukla@sifymail.com" does not exist<br>
LINE 1: select update_user(1,"amarshukla@sifymail.com","hell");
```

Can someone point me where am I making a mistake?

Comment: It's been a while since I've tried PL/Python, but the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html) seem to suggest that your `prepare` call should have the argument types in a single List, i.e. `plan=plpy.prepare("UPDATE ...", ["int", "text", "text"])`, not  `["int"] ["text"]["text"]` as you wrote.